# How do I access the current record in an asp:Repeater?

Tags: asp.net

Suppose I have an asp:Repeater that I am using to display a list of names and phone numbers.

```
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
 <ItemTemplate>
  <p><%# Eval("name") %></p>
  <p><%# Eval("phoneNumber") %></p>
 </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Now, let's make it more fun.  Let's suppose that there is one or more phone number per name.  I feel like I could use a repeater within a repeater to repeat the phone numbers.  I could also use a `for` loop in my asp code.  However, the `Eval` function is the only way I know of to access the current record at runtime and Eval only returns a string and only runs in <%# Eval("X") %>.  How can I get the list of phone numbers that is a member of the current record?

Answer (score 1):

First, change

```
<%# Eval("name") %>
```

to

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="lblName" Text='<%# Eval("name") %>'></asp:Label>
```

Then  in the code-behind you can use FindControl()

```
foreach (RepeaterItem currentItem in Repeater1.Items)
{
    Label l = (Label)currentItem.FindControl("lblName");

    // Now you can access it as you would any other label.
    Response.Write(l.Text);
}
```

Comment: WOW!  That is convoluted!  Is there really no simple way to refer to the current record in the datasource in my asp code?

Comment: no.  The data source is not there on the next postback.  Just the Repeater items.